# apktool error while decompiling .apk

Tags: smali, apktool

I got this error while I was decompiling an .apk by apktool. Although It doesn't appear for all apk files.
Also I had installed these three frameworks:

```
framework-res.apk
SystemUI.apk
twframework-res.apk
```

I tried two different versions of framework-res.apk but it didn't help.
What should I do?

Thank you

```
I: Baksmaling...
Error occured while disassembling class Ldxoptimizer.con; - skipping class
java.io.IOException: The parameter is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
        at org.jf.baksmali.baksmali.disassembleDexFile(baksmali.java:176)
        at brut.androlib.src.SmaliDecoder.decode(SmaliDecoder.java:49)
        at brut.androlib.src.SmaliDecoder.decode(SmaliDecoder.java:34)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.decodeSourcesSmali(Androlib.java:74)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:89)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:146)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:77)
I: Loading resource table...
I: Loaded.
I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
I: Loading resource table from file: C:\Users\ShayanK\apktool\framework\1.apk
I: Loaded.
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
hardwareAccelerated, value=0xffffffff
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
hardwareAccelerated, value=0xffffffff
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
hardwareAccelerated, value=0xffffffff
I: Regular manifest package...
I: Decoding file-resources...
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
exitFadeDuration, value=0x00000190
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x3f333333
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
previewImage, value=0x7f020001
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x00000000
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x3f000000
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x3f000000
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x3e99999a
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
previewImage, value=0x7f020002
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x3f000000
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x3f000000
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
showAsAction, value=0x00000000
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
alpha, value=0x00000000
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
previewImage, value=0x7f020002
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=
previewImage, value=0x7f020001
I: Decoding values */* XMLs...
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.err.UndefinedResObject: resource spec:
0x01030119
        at brut.androlib.res.data.ResPackage.getResSpec(ResPackage.java:61)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.ResTable.getResSpec(ResTable.java:58)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.ResTable.getResSpec(ResTable.java:54)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.value.ResReferenceValue.getReferent(ResReferen
ceValue.java:62)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.value.ResReferenceValue.encodeAsResXml(ResRefe
renceValue.java:46)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.value.ResScalarValue.encodeAsResXmlAttr(ResSca
larValue.java:44)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.value.ResStyleValue.serializeToResValuesXml(Re
sStyleValue.java:48)
        at brut.androlib.res.data.value.ResBagValue.serializeToResValuesXml(ResB
agValue.java:40)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.generateValuesFile(AndrolibResour
ces.java:440)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.decode(AndrolibResources.java:243
)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.decodeResourcesFull(Androlib.java:115)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:114)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:146)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, please make sure you have upgraded your apktool to the latest version, you can follow the instruction [here](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) to install it.

Then you need to upgrade your framework file. When I tried to decompile some apk file, it will show error like this

> Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.err.UndefinedResObject:
>   resource spec: 0x01010462

It is caused by your framework file didn't support the latest android version, I solved the problem by:

1. delete the origin framwork file, mine is located in

> I: Loading resource table from file: /Users/csc/Library/apktool/framework/1.apk

2. Get a proper framework apk

   Take my phone(nexus 5, android 5.1) for exmaple, you can find the framework apk in /system/framework/, and it called framework-res.apk. Using adb pull to copy it on your computer, rename it to 1.apk, copy it to your framework file directory.
3. Try again and problem solved.

   [here](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/#frameworks) is the detailed origin tutorial.